# Hibernate @ManyToOne Cascade working super weirdly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-one

I have a project where every `Student` can be tested by a `Tester`, and a single tester can test many students.
I need students to know their testers - so this is a unidirectional Many to One.

Tester:

```java
@Entity
public class Tester
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Tester(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected Tester(){}

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("Tester [id=%s, name=%s]", this.id, this.name);
    }
}
```

Student:

```java
@Entity
public class Student
{
    @Id
    private Long id; //this shouldn't be auto incremented

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tester_id")
    private Tester tester;

    public Student(Long id, int age, Tester tester)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.tester = tester;
    }

    protected Student(){}

    public int getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }

    public Tester getTester()
    {
        return this.tester;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("Student [id=%s, age=%s, tester=%s]", this.id, this.age, this.tester);
    }
}
```

When I run this code:

```java
Tester tester = new Tester("Tester");
Student student = new Student(1L, 27, tester);
this.studentRepository.save(student);
```

I expect both entities to be saved due to the cascade, but instead I get an sql error because the tester's name is magically null?!?
If I remove the `nullable = false` from the column, the tester entity is saved but with null in the name column...
What the hell did I do wrong?

Please don't recommend saving the Tester first, it's not helping because I want to understand what's **wrong** with my code.

Comment: Please post the code where you are creating the student and teacher and saving them. Most likely that is where your problem is.

Comment: @ewramner I thought I did, fixed!

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/entity-persistence.html#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies, it may be that Spring assumes your student is an existing entity as it has an id. The linked document describes how to fix that with a transient flag. EDIT: or you could call the entityManager's persist method directly without Spring.

Comment: @ewramner Please post this as an answer :) Thank you so much, this was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comment. As per [the Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/entity-persistence.html#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies), the student is assumed to already exist as it has an id:

> By default Spring Data JPA inspects first if there is a
> Version-property of non-primitive type. If there is, the entity is
> considered new if the value of that property is null. Without such a
> Version-property Spring Data JPA inspects the identifier property of
> the given entity. If the identifier property is null, then the entity
> is assumed to be new. Otherwise, it is assumed to be not new.

This can be fixed by adding a version column or by using a @Transient flag that controls if the entity is new or not (described in more detail in the linked document).

Alternatively, the entity manager's persist method can be used without Spring.